# Flutter - Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'

Tags: android, flutter

Having a lot of issues with building an apk in flutter lately,
I've been using guides, and a lot of questions here, so far I've fixed most of the bugs that have been popping up, but i write in the terminal `flutter build apk` , it will result in these messages:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
   > com.android.ide.common.signing.KeytoolException: Failed to read key key from store "C:\Users\user\Desktop\codecanyon-J8lmW676-cirilla-multipurpose-flu
tter-wordpress-app (1)\app\cirilla\android\app\upload-keystore.jks": No key with alias 'key' found in keystore C:\Users\user\Desktop\codecanyon-J8lmW676-ci
rilla-multipurpose-flutter-wordpress-app (1)\app\cirilla\android\app\upload-keystore.jks

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Here is my key.properties:

```
storePassword=xxx
keyPassword=xxx
keyAlias=key
storeFile= C:/Users/user/Desktop/codecanyon-J8lmW676-cirilla-multipurpose-flutter-wordpress-app (1)/app/cirilla/android/app/upload-keystore.jks
```

and here is my grade file:

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('app/key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: don't change the id (;
        applicationId "com.example.censored"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

is there a chance it's because of the folder names in the path? or just something i've missed in the code?

Comment: why you not change your application id name

Comment: I did change, In the code itself it has a name of a customer of mine who asked for help in this program

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well seems like it all happened because of this line in the Gradle file:

```
 throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
```

GradleException() doesn't work anymore in the newer versions for some reason, I've changed it to FileNotFoundException(), oh and also made sure that there is only 1 file named key.properties and he's under /android/
and it started working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I'm writing in case someone else encounters the same problem.
In my case I got this error because I added key.properties.dart extension to my key.properties file. :(