# Unable to build apk in flutter as am getting error in android/app/build.gradle

Tags: flutter, firebase, gradle, apk

When I tried to run flutter build apk,i was unable to generate apk and its showing error in the build gradle.

Error I got:-
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.tasks.PackageAndroidArtifact$IncrementalSplitterRunnable
> SigningConfig "release" is missing required property "storeFile".

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 5s
Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...                           66.5s
Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1

am getting the above  error.How to resolve it?

My build.gradle file:-

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader -\>
localProperties.load(reader)
}
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}
android {
namespace "com.example.tis_root01"
compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    
    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

defaultConfig {
// TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
applicationId "com.example.tis_root01"
// You can update the following values to match your application needs.
// For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
minSdkVersion Math.max(flutter.minSdkVersion,24)
targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
versionName flutterVersionName
multiDexEnabled true
}

signingConfigs {
release {
keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
storePassword keystoreProperties\['storePassword'\]
}
}
buildTypes {
release {

        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
       
    }

}
}

flutter {
source '../..'
}

dependencies {
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Comment: Looks like a relevant answer: [Answer: Flutter - Execution failed for task ':app:packageRelease'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69536103/21272987)

Comment: Run with debug and see if the error persist

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the `key.properties` file inside the Android folder of your project.

I think this error is related to it because it is specified in it

```
SigningConfig "release" is missing required property "storeFile".
```

And make sure to use the same `variable` name as written inside the signing Configs inside your `build.gradle` file.

Use this

```
signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
        keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
        storeFile keystoreProperties['storeFile'] ? file(keystoreProperties['storeFile']) : null
        storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
    }
}
```

and make sure you have

`keyAlias`= You key alias

`keyPassword` = Your key password

`storeFile` = key store file path

`storePassword` = You key store password

Check you have all those inside your `key.properties` file